# How to programmatically watermark a video file

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, avfoundation

I have a video file recorded from the iPhone camera by the user. Then, I want to generate a new video file that includes a PNG layer that goes on top of it.

How would one do such a task in `Objective-C`?

I'm happy to produce my code that shows how I record the video file, but you can just assume it's a normal .mov file.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Before saving the file locally create a CATextLayer and attach it to the video. I believe this code will help you which I had written for one my application.

```
- (void)applyVideoEffectsToComposition:(AVMutableVideoComposition *)composition size:(CGSize)size
{
    NSArray *fieldsArray = overlayFieldsArray;
    // 1 - Set up the text layer
    CATextLayer *subtitle1Text = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
    subtitle1Text.wrapped=YES;
    subtitle1Text.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentLeft;
    [subtitle1Text setFont:@"Helvetica-Bold"];
    [subtitle1Text setFontSize:textSize];
    [subtitle1Text setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, fieldsArray.count*textSize+20) ];


    NSMutableString *layerText = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];

    for(NSDictionary *fieldDictionary in fieldsArray){

        [layerText appendFormat:@" %@ :",[[fieldDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]];

        [layerText appendFormat:@" %@ \n",[_candidateDictionary valueForKey:[[fieldDictionary allValues] objectAtIndex:0]]];
    }


    [subtitle1Text setString:layerText];

    [subtitle1Text setForegroundColor:[[UIColor colorForText] CGColor]];

    // 2 - The usual overlay
    CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
    overlayLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorForLayer].CGColor;
    overlayLayer.opacity=0.5f;
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(600, 600);
    UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:textSize];
    CGSize layerTextSize = [layerText sizeWithFont:myFont
                                 constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                                     lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, layerTextSize.width*1.1, fieldsArray.count*textSize+20);
    [overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    [overlayLayer addSublayer:subtitle1Text];

    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];

    CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];


    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, layerTextSize.width*1.1, fieldsArray.count*textSize+20);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];



    composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
                                 videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

}
```